# Visualforce Lookup field search icon not working on Salesforce Mobile App (Android)

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, inputfield, bug, salesforce-mobile-app

I've a Visualforce Page overriding New & Edit standard buttons. On Salesforce Mobile App (Android) only, the lookup field search icon does not work. It throws users to login page and when they separately login again to the popup they cannot select the record.

While in iOS Salesforce App, everything works normally, the search window shows records to select and on clicking record link it closes the dialog.

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true" standardController="MyCustomObj__c">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
      <apex:inputField value="{!MyCustomObj__c.LookupField__c}" />
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I remember no issues in past on Android app, but it seems to not working on Android now at all.

Salesforce support isn't following up without premier support and I don't know how to get this resolved by myself.

The above code is very basic skeleton. My original code is a bit complex and it has some background processing done  on save of record as well, which I'm hiding here, since my issues is reproducible with the simplest form here as well.